# Substitute driver in a running kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I would like to know if it is possible to substitute a driver in a running kernel. The driver I want to replace can be either built-in or loadable. I am interrested in both possibilities.

To be more precise, this is a usb/ethernet driver that I want to replace and make test on it. If my driver is not correct, I may lose access to all my usb devices and so lose my keyboard/mouse, that would be embarrassing. So what will happen if there are 2 drivers with the same purpose that run at the same time ?

Thank you for your informations !

Comment: I think it would be better if you update this information in the question itself instead of in comment section.

Comment: It can't be like you are describing, but you may use some tricks for testing purposes, and yes, you may screw things up, reboot will be needed.